# TableView CustomCell ISSUE?

Tags: ios4

I had a customcell for my tableView.Recently I have changed some controls in the cells.I am facing a problem.The new controls are not showing when I am running my application.

Even I removed all the labels, uibuttons from the cellView.But nothing is working.It's something like it's stored the controls in the memory.How can I get rid of this?

Comment: have you deleted the app from the device/simulator? Sometimes this helps.

Comment: yes i tried by removing it from the simulator list.But not working.Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean the project and build again.

Comment: How can i clean the project?I didn't get you!

Comment: if you using xcode4, go to product menu and click the "clean" and for older versions of xcode, its in build menu